# How to create a link to a website in vb code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url, code-behind

It may be simple but the search words in Google give too many irrelevant results.

```
Protected Sub Menu1_MenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As MenuEventArgs) Handles Menu1.MenuItemClick
    If e.Item.Text = "SomeItem" Then
      'The link goes here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Response.Redirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com")`

Comment: You can't open a new tab in the code behind as far as I know without using `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to generate javascript code to run on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Response.Redirect` if you want to send the current page to a new url:

```
Protected Sub Menu1_MenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As MenuEventArgs) Handles Menu1.MenuItemClick
    If e.Item.Text = "SomeItem" Then
        Response.Redirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
    End If
End Sub
```

To open a new url in a new window/tab you would have to use javascript. Normally I would recommend just putting the javascript directly onto the aspx page but in the event that the url will use data from the code behind to generate the url you can use the `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` function.

```
Protected Sub Menu1_MenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As MenuEventArgs) Handles Menu1.MenuItemClick
    If e.Item.Text = "SomeItem" Then
        Dim sURL As String = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "script", "window.open('" & sURL + "', 'popup_window');", True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, this answer is useful